# Allow file types AND 1 specific file

Tags: .htaccess

I am having this in my htaccess file:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|ttf|svg|woff|eot)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

But I also want to allow 1 specific html file, ABC.html to be accessible. How do I put this code in together with the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `OR` separation:

```
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|ttf|svg|woff|eot)$|ABC.html">
```